# onRequestPermissionsResult calling automatically with not Gratned results

Tags: android, permissions, uri

My problem is that

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
```

calling immediatelly after

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
```

and always denied: grantResults[0] == -1 (not granted). 
But I even can't see a standard popup with permission requesting. 
I added permission to Manifest, OS Oreo. 
I switched on manually this permission in app's settings. But  "Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri. ...
requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: If you are developing: uninstall the app and try again. You may have clicked deny with "remember my decision" checked. If users are reporting this error, then you must account for users not wanting your app the access the sdcard...

Comment: I'm a developer. I haven't clicked "deny and remember my choise". I didn't see any popup with choice, granted manually in settings. But still getting 'denied'

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: @sneharc yes, the problem was in manifest merge. External library's manifest overloads my origin manifest, so I was need to add tools:node="merge"
        tools:replace="android:label" (but this is only my personal case, just for information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in manifest merge. External library's manifest overrides my origin manifest, so I was needed to add to /application/ tag:

```
tools:node="merge" 
tools:replace="android:label"
```

(but this is only my personal case, just for information).